# Calculate time left until battery is discharged?

Tags: linux, algorithm, battery, batterylevel

I want to calculate the time until the battery in my laptop has discharged. The data I can use is available via sysfs, but I'm not sure which files and algorithm to use:

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/ | sort
alarm
charge_full
charge_full_design
charge_now
current_now
cycle_count
device
manufacturer
model_name
power
present
serial_number
status
subsystem
technology
type
uevent
voltage_min_design
voltage_no
```

What is the correct algorithm to determine time left in hours and minutes before the battery is empty?

Comment: Try something like: charge_now/charge_full = %_left, time_left = (uptime/%_left) - uptime;   (I'm just pulling it out of my ear -- it looks close in a couple of quick cases)

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the time left, use `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW` / `POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW`  This will get you seconds left.

The current now is a snapshot of the consumption rate, and the charge now is the amount left.  Using `acpi -b` will give you around the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment above...

charge_now = 75% (case 1), 25% (case 2)

charge_full = 100%
uptime = 2 hours

=> %_used = 0.75 (case 1), 25% (case 2)

(case 1) time_left = (2 hours/0.75) - 2 hours = (2.67 - 2) hours

(case 2) time_left = (2 hours/0.25) - 2 hours = (8 - 2) hours

Your mileage may vary... :^)

Comment: 2 hours uptime, charge is 25 %, and 6 hours left? And at 75 % 0,67 h left? Seems odd to me...

Comment: They are examples (off the top of my head) for different situations or different batteries. They don't make sense for the same laptop, so pick some other inputs and see if the outputs make sense.